# How do I prove this inequality using Borel-Caretheodory inequality?

Tags: complex-analysis

> (Borel-Caratheodory)
>
> Suppose $f(z)$ is analytic in the disk $|z|\leq R$. Let $M(r)$ be the maximum of $f$ on $B(0,r)$ and $A(R)$ be the maximum of $Re(f)$ on $B(0,R)$. Then, for $0<r<R$, $M(r)\leq \frac{2r}{R-r} A(R) + \frac{R+r}{R-r} |f(0)|$.

Define $N(r)$ as the maximum of $f^{(n)}(z)$ on $B(0,r)$.

I'm trying to prove that $\frac{N(r)}{n!} \leq \frac{2^{n+2}R}{(R-r)^{n+1}} [A(R) + |f(0)|]$ for $0<r<R$.

Fix $|z_0|=r$ and take the contour $|z|=\frac{R+r}{2}$.

Then, $|z-z_0|\geq |z|-|z_0| = \frac{R-r}{2} $ on this contour. Applying Cauchy integral formula, $|\frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}|\leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{|z|=\frac{R+r}{2}} |f(z)|/|z-z_0|^{n+1} |dz|$.

I thought this would lead the result, but this does not work.

How do I prove the above bound for $N(r)$?